# javascript is not working if i add dynamic script tag

Tags: javascript

i want to add dynamic javascript tag on the body

```
window.onload = function() {
     var e = document.createElement('span');
     e.innerHTML ='<script type="text/javascript">alert("hello");</script>';
     document.body.insertBefore(e,document.body.childNodes[0]);                
}
```

in the above example the javascript which is being loaded using innerHTML is not working

is there any workaround for this problem

Comment: a script tag inside a span is nonsense.

Comment: Why would you possibly want to do this? It's just the same as putting a script tag in the document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The clean way would be the following:

```
var e = document.createElement('script');
e.type = "text/javascript";  // not needed in HTML5
e.innerHTML ='alert("hello");'; // or .text or create a new textnode

document.body.appendChild(e);
```